# How to listen hardware keys in react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a project where i need to take photo with selfie stick.

So i tested with selfie stick but what it does it just call the volume up button. So now i need to listen the volume up button or event that increase volume.

Any packages to listen volume up button in react-native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [react-native-system-setting](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting) and [react-native-volume-control](https://github.com/Kennytian/react-native-volume-control)